# What is root-build in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt, intellij-15

Whenever I create an sbt project in intellij, I get something like this:

[image]

What is `root-build` here, and why is it labeled as "sources root"?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an sbt project in IntelliJ, the [default root](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Multi-Project.html#Default+root+project) of sbt, called `root`, is added as a module. You can see this by right-clicking on the project and clicking *Open Module Settings*. That is what `root-build` refers to.

You can read a description of content roots on the [IDEA site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing (at least I am being honest) but I believe SBT configuration itself can be considered a "development project" and so is setup as a separate module called "project" for its build, i.e. the build of the build configuration. Notice it has its own "target" directory.